# How to load the right pane without reloading header/footer or leftnav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a web app (HTML/Bootstrap/jquery) which has header,footer,leftnav and right pane. The content of the right pane would be a separate html page which will be loaded based on what is clicked in the left nav.

I got individual pages with HTML for header/footer/leftnav replicated for each content page. But I only would like to have the right pane content to be loaded without reloading the other components.

Heres an example, upon click on left nav item.. only the content of the right pane changes:
 http://play.raaga.com/myraaga

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ".load()" function of jquery.

```
$('selector-of-the-panel').load('url');
```

[jQuery .load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Wow.. nice, thats what I was looking for.

Comment: Are there any ways to highlight the appropriate item in left nav based on the url. ex: domain.com/daily/installs would open 'Daily' in left nav tree and highlight 'Installs' in the submenu. Eventually fetch installs.html from server to load into the rightpane.

Comment: Are you saying, if the user inform the URL: "domain.com/daily/installs", you want to open the "installs.html" in the Right menu and than Highlight the menu "Installs"?

Comment: Yes, highlight Installs under Daily subtree.

Comment: So yes, It's possible. with the object "location" in JS you can get the URL, so you just need to add some extra clauses to validate the names, like IF's and ELSE's. eg: typing "location.href" in JS will returns the href (URL) of the current page. See more examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

The example you included looks pretty close to jQuery UI's .tabs() widget, which you can use with ajax to load your different html pages: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax  For a vertical nav-like look, see: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical